# ubuntu 22.04.03 do not reconize size 16:9 / resoluton of monitor samsung 1366x768 60HZ

Tags: xubuntu, monitor, samsung

could anybody help me with the files configuration and commands in order to use this optimal configuration. in this moment xubuntu only recognize 4:3  1024 x 768